# XNA Camera Rotation Around Z Axis

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating a camera for a 3D game. The camera is made up of the following variables:

```
static Vector3 cameraLookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
static Vector3 cameraPosition;
static float cameraZoom = 25; // Field of view 
const int cameraZoomNear = 3; // The furthest the camera can zoom in 
const int cameraZoomFar = 45; // The furthest the camera can zoom out 
static float cameraPitch; // Amount to change the pitch 
static float cameraRotation; // Amount to change the rotation
```

By default the 'cameraLookAt' is at (0, 0, 0) and the 'cameraPosition' is at (0, 0, 10) this means the camera is directly above the 'cameraLookAt' position giving a birds eye view of the object below (a red green & blue xyz plane test object)

'cameraLookAt' can be moved along the x and y axis and the 'cameraPosition' is then calculated relative to the 'cameraLookAt' position and the current values of 'cameraPitch' and 'cameraRotation'

Currently you can move around the x/y axis fine and change the pitch of the camera to go from a birdeye view to a ground view. The bit I'm having trouble with is getting the camera rotation to work.

When the rotation value is changed it only has any effect if the pitch has changed - from the default when the program starts (which is looking directly down at the 'cameraLookAt')

When the value does change you can rotate around the Z axis but the view also rolls so by the time you have rotated 180 degrees the camera has rolled 180 degrees as well and your view is upside down.

Below is the code which works out where the 'cameraPosition' is and I'm sure the fix lines within those lines.

```
        cameraPosition = cameraLookAt + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);

        Vector3 temp = Vector3.Normalize(cameraPosition - cameraLookAt); //creates a unit length vector that points in the direction from 'lookAt' to 'position'
        cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(cameraPosition - cameraLookAt, Matrix.CreateRotationX(cameraPitch)) + cameraLookAt;
        cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(cameraPosition - cameraLookAt, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(cameraRotation)) + cameraLookAt;

        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraLookAt, new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraZoom), graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio, nearClip, farClip);
```

Also here is a q&a that I found to help me code it in the first place [XNA Rotate Camera Around It's CreateLookAt "Target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906907/xna-rotate-camera-around-its-createlookat-target)

Answer (score 1):

The offset should be rotated without change its length and then is added to the camera position.

I think it should be this way:

```
   offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);

   Vector3 rotatedOffset = Vector3.Transform( offset, 
                                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(cameraPitch) 
                                      * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(cameraRotation));

   cameraPosition = cameraLookAt + rotatedOffset;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't actually solve the problem, in the end I got some help over at http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/105840/624190.aspx#624190 he used a different approach rather than trying to fix my code but it did create some problems of its own... still working on a final solution.