# How to Rotate a Camera - Camera Rotation

Tags: c#, 3d, camera, rotation

I am wondering if there is a variable or way i could use to rotate the camera in my game. I can move it along xyz axis's but i cannot figure out how to rotate it! :O

***Here are the variables:***

```
    Model spaceShip;
    float aspectRatio;
    Vector3 modelPosition = Vector3.Zero;
    float modelRotation = 0f;

    Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0f, 50f, 5000f);
```

***Here is how its draw(the model(a spaceship)):***

```
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[spaceShip.Bones.Count];
        spaceShip.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in spaceShip.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * Matrix.CreateRotationY(this.modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(this.modelPosition);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(this.cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45f), aspectRatio, 1f,200000f);
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

***and this aspect ratio is loaded in:***

aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906907/xna-rotate-camera-around-its-createlookat-target

Also, look at this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197901.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to rotate root container of your scene (which should not contain the camera, for camera you should have another container outside the root) around the camera look direction vector